How to deal with OneDrive stuck in an SSO loop?
One of our domain managed laptops is having issues signing in to OneDrive. Once we enter the user's email, it directs to the SSO "handshake" but then gets stuck in a loop of a "Finish signing in with your work or school account / Signing in" and a "Loading / One moment" pop-up, which cycles multiple times per second. This seems to imply that One Drive is handing off to the SSO login process, which is completing, but then unable to hand it back somehow.
After closing the pop-up during this process, the sign-in page shows:

There was a problem signing you in.
Please try again after a few minute (Error Code: 0x8004de44).

Googling this error comes up with few and unhelpful results along the lines of "nvm - fixed it".
I have followed these steps with no change.
The same license works with Office no issues, and any other applications tied to the SSO, and it only has this issue on this particular laptop - have tried to log in to OneDrive with these credentials on other devices with no issues.
I believe a simple solution would be to simply re-image the laptop, however there are a lot of documents that have not been backed up, and if this were to occur on multiple devices it would be easier to have a solution that could recover the PC, rather than backup and reset.
I have also tried to log in to a separate user on the same machine, with no issues.

have you tried resetting it? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reset-onedrive-34701e00-bf7b-42db-b960-84905399050c

@FrankThomas yes - these are the same instructions followed in the link I provided

So after some investigation, I found that:

the same user on other devices does not experience this issue
other users on the same device do not experience this issue

So a while not actually finding the solution to this specific problem, a solution I did find was to:

delete the user registry key in: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\ProfileList\{User Registry key}
In order to preserve the files, rename the old C:\Users folder (e.g. username.old)

Whatever is connecting the profile to the instance of OneDrive is then removed, and the files are still accessible through that Users directory.
Again, I don't know what the root of the problem is, but this seems to bypass it.
